# Merge [inferred-type] and [type-inference]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-inference) has a little more than 2k questions, the tag info starts with

> Type inference is the process of inferring types for programs automatically, using rules defined by a type system, thereby allowing the programmer to omit writing (sometimes very extensive) type annotations.

[inferred-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inferred-type) has 61 questions, the tag info starts with

> Type inference refers to the automatic deduction of the type of an expression in a programming language.

Given that the tag info starts with the exact two words, the former tag is made up from, it seems like a logical step to merge the two. If I understand correctly, [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Binferred-type%5D+%5Btype-inference%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) shows that at least 12 of the questions tagged [inferred-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inferred-type), are also tagged [type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-inference), leaving 49 questions only tagged with [inferred-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inferred-type).

Following a question by [1201ProgramAlarm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5231607/1201programalarm) in the comments: I think [inferred-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inferred-type) should also become a synonym of [type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-inference).

Comment: Should `inferred-type` be made into a synonym of `type-inference`?

Comment: I knew I missed something; yes, I think that would make sense, given the similarity.